# Looping through list to store variables in dictionary runs in error

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-views

What I want to do:
Get user input from HTML form, store input in variables within Django and perform calculations with variables.

To accomplish that, I use following code:

```
my_var = requst.POST.get('my_var')
```

To prevent having `'None'` stored in `'my_var'` when a Django page is first rendered, I usually use 
`if my_var == None:
    my_var = 1`

To keep it simple when using a bunch of variables I came up with following idea:

1. I store all variable names in a list
2. I loop through list and create a dictionary with variable names as key and user input as value

For that I wrote this code in python which works great:

```
list_eCar_properties = [
'car_manufacturer',
'car_model',
'car_consumption',]

dict_sample_eCar = {
    'car_manufacturer' : "Supr-Duper",
    'car_model' : "Lightning 1000",
    'car_consumption' : 15.8,
}

dict_user_eCar = {
}

my_dict = {
    'car_manufacturer' : None,
    'car_model' : None,
    'car_consumption' : None,
}

for item in list_eCar_properties:
    if my_dict[item] == None:
        dict_user_eCar[item] = dict_sample_eCar[item]
    else:
        dict_user_eCar[item] = my_dict[item]


print(dict_user_eCar)
```

Works great - when I run the code, a dictionary (dict_user_eCar) is created where user input (in this case `None` simulated by using a second dictionary `my_dict`) is stored. When User leaves input blank - Data from dict_sample_eCar is used.

Now, when I transfer that code to my Django view things don't work not as nice anymore. Code as follows:

```
def Verbrauchsrechner_eAuto(request):
list_eCar_properties = [
    'car_manufacturer',
    'car_model',
    'car_consumption',
]

dict_model_eCar = {
    'car_manufacturer' : "Supr-Duper",
    'car_model' : "Lightning 1000",
    'car_consumption' : 15.8,
}

dict_user_eCar = {
}

for item in list_eCar_properties:
    dict_user_eCar[item] = dict_model_eCar[item]

    context = {
        'dict_user_eCar' : dict_user_eCar,
        'dict_model_eCar' : dict_model_eCar,
        'list_eCar_properties' : list_eCar_properties,
    }

    return render(request, 'eAuto/Verbrauchsrechner_eAuto.html', context = context)
```

Result: The page gets rendered with only the first dictionary entry. All others are left out. In this cases only `car_manufacturer` gets rendered to html-page.

Comment: Your "return render()" statement is inside of the for loop. Looks to me like it should be after the loop. Additionally, it looks like your definition of "context = {}" should be outside of the loop also?

Comment: Absolutely - thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry folks - as I was reviewing my post, I realized, that I had a major srew-up at the last part's indentation:
`context` and `return` both were part of the for-loop which obviously resulted in a page-rendering after the first loop.
I corrected the code as follows:

```
for item in list_eCar_properties:
    dict_user_eCar[item] = dict_model_eCar[item]

context = {
    'dict_user_eCar' : dict_user_eCar,
    'dict_model_eCar' : dict_model_eCar,
    'list_eCar_properties' : list_eCar_properties,
}

return render(request, 'eAuto/Verbrauchsrechner_eAuto.html', context = context)`
```

Since I didn't want the time I spend to write this post to be wasted - I simply posted it anyway - even though I found the mistake myself.

Lessons learned for a Newbie in programming:

1. To many comments in your own code might result in a big confusion
2. Try to be precise and keep code neat and tidy
3. Do 1 and 2 **before** writing long posts in stackoverflow

Maybe someone else will benefit from this.